# React-odometer-js with next.js and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new in programming. I need to implement a count up animation in my project. I'm using next.js, typescript and react-odometer.js for this. Everything is working correctly, but the problem is I'm getting an error and I can't fix that error. I'll be very thankful if anyone help me about this. Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import one from "public/images/counter/one.png";
import two from "public/images/counter/two.png";
import three from "public/images/counter/three.png";
import four from "public/images/counter/four.png";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css";
const Odometer = dynamic(import("react-odometerjs"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => null,
});

const Counter = () => {
  const [fValue, setfValue] = useState(0);
  const [sValue, setsValue] = useState(0);
  const [tValue, settValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setfValue(300);
      setsValue(300);
      settValue(300);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <section className="section counter pb-0">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <div className="counter__inner">
              <div
                className="counter__item wow fadeInUp"
                data-wow-duration="600ms"
                data-wow-delay="300ms"
              >
                <div className="counter__item-inner">
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__thumb">
                    <Image src={one} priority alt="Image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__content">
                    <h4 className="h4">
                      <span className="odometer">
                        <Odometer
                          value={fValue}
                          format="(,ddd)"
                          theme="default"
                        />
                      </span>
                      <span>+</span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p className="h6">Certified Professionals</p>
              </div>
              <div
                className="counter__item wow fadeInUp"
                data-wow-duration="600ms"
                data-wow-delay="600ms"
              >
                <div className="counter__item-inner">
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__thumb">
                    <Image src={two} priority alt="Image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__content">
                    <h4 className="h4">
                      <span className="odometer">
                        <Odometer
                          value={sValue}
                          format="(,ddd)"
                          theme="default"
                        />
                      </span>
                      <span>%</span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p className="h6">Sales Lift</p>
              </div>
              <div
                className="counter__item wow fadeInUp"
                data-wow-duration="600ms"
                data-wow-delay="900ms"
              >
                <div className="counter__item-inner">
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__thumb">
                    <Image src={three} priority alt="Image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__content">
                    <h4 className="h4">
                      <span className="odometer">
                        <Odometer
                          value={tValue}
                          format="(,ddd)"
                          theme="default"
                        />
                      </span>
                      <span>%</span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p className="h6">Faster Delivery</p>
              </div>
              <div
                className="counter__item wow fadeInUp"
                data-wow-duration="600ms"
                data-wow-delay="1200ms"
              >
                <div className="counter__item-inner">
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__thumb">
                    <Image src={four} priority alt="Image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="counter__item-inner__content">
                    <h4 className="h4">
                      <span
                        className="odometer"
                        data-odometer-final="35"
                      ></span>
                      <span>%</span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p className="h6">Lower Cost</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

and this is the error I'm getting in the browser:

```
1 of 3 unhandled errors
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <span>.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
Component Stack
div
ReactOdometer
Call Stack
throwOnHydrationMismatch
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12507:0)
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12520:0)
updateHostComponent
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19902:0)
beginWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (21618:0)
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4164:0)
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4213:0)
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (27451:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopConcurrent
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26543:0)
renderRootConcurrent
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26505:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
workLoop
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

Comment: Potentially add "use client"; at the top of the file, and remove the dynamic import.